# Retrieve toolstripbutton using UIAutomation

Tags: c#, microsoft-ui-automation

Using UIAutomation on windows Forms, I'm trying to retrieve any control under mouse on a specific form.
The goal is to work on controls of an app, retrieving and acting on them.

The problem I'm facing since so many times is that I can't find a toolstripbutton.
Everytime I'm getting a pane (not parent nor child of the toolstripbutton I want, but parent's sibling).

This is the toolstripbutton I want to retrieve : [image: screenshot 1].

The same control but in Inspect.exe (highlighted: the control I'm getting) : [image: screenshot 2]

I though that it was because of z order of the controls, then I tried using sibling controls, for controls where their bounds contains the mouse (for getting all controls under the cursor anyway their z order).
That fails because the toolstripbutton isn't retrieved.

I currently use UIAutomation and not CodedUI, because I need to run a custom program which retrieve controls and executes automatic tests on a specific server, but I actually have the Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 licence installed on my machine, but a second licence (for the server) and a third licence for a colleague for work with me on it would be a bit expensive.

Remembering that the programs have to retrieve dynamically the controls under the mouse, may someone gives me any idea which can help me to investigate deeper ?

Thanks & Greetings

Method used:

```
var aimed = AutomationElement.FromPoint(new System.Windows.Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y));
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by **work around**.

I made a recursive method that search deeper in the children for controls which contains the mouse (BoundingRectangle.Contains` method).
In that way, I can find the controls within the toolstrip.

But `AutomationElement.FromPoint` method doesn't search inside the toolstrip.